# В чем разница между git и github?

Tags: git, github

Какая между ними разница? Вроде и то и другое система контроля версий. Почему в одних случаях используют git, а в других github?

Comment: в чём разница между двумя группами: {svn, hg (Mercurial), git, bzr (Bazaar), cvs} (VCS: системы контроля версий) и {`github.com`, `bitbucket.org`, `gitlab.com`, `coding.net`, `launchpad.net`, `savannah.gnu.org`}  (web-сервисы: работа с VCS репозиториями, интеграция с CI, bug trackers, hosting документации, организация проектов, взаимодействия между разработчиками, итд)?

Comment: Git - это система контроля версий, а GitHub - один из множества веб-сервисов, использующих эту систему.

Comment: Git — распределённая система контроля версий. Пропущено слово "распределённая".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Если грубо и в двух словах:

git - это сама программа, которая осуществляет контроль версий. Она делает репозитории, которые нужно где-то хранить.

github - это сайт, где можно хранить репозитории, созданные в git

Поэтому фраза "в одних случаях используют git а в другом github" - неверна. Даже когда для хранения репозитория используется github, для управления этим репозиторием всё-равно используется git.

То есть это всё равно, как спросить - почему люди для поиска информации иногда используют поиск google.com, а в других случаях - браузер Google Chrome.